# Simple code works in IE but not other browsers

Tags: javascript

The code snippet below (shortened, but I'm sure you get the gist of it) works in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox, Chrome or Edge. **I cannot alter the code** as it's part of a web-based ticketing system which we use at work but can someone please tell me if I can change a setting in Firefox or Chrome to make it work?

```
function checkCallLogIsValid (userId){
 var t = document.getElementById('CallType');
 if (t.value == '' || t.value == '0'){
  alert ("You must provide a valid call type");
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Lower down:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="/calls/call_log.asp?LogID=&ContactID=16440">
 <select name="CallType" id="select3"><option value="0">Select</option><option value="5">Accounts</option><option value="58">Autoclave Service</option>
 </select>
 <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit"  value="Save" onClick="return checkCallLogIsValid(0);">
</form>
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean exactly? Have you checked the console for errors? Or is there some other unexpected behaviour you can describe to us? Also which version(s) of IE is this supported in? The functionality varies greatly between versions.

Comment: what defines "it does not work" ?

Comment: This code is wrong: `document.getElementById('CallType');` as the call type element has a different id, but the same name. I'm surprised it works in IE.

Comment: Actually I can see that `document.getElementById('CallType');` will not return anything because there is no element with the ID "CallType". Presumably IE has a non-standard feature where it will try and select by the "name" property instead

Comment: @Adder old versions of IE would return elements by name via `getElementById()`

Comment: `var t = document.getElementById('CallType') || document.getElementById('select3')`? Or `<select name="CallType" id="CallType">`?

Comment: Bottom line: if you can't change the code, you're out of luck. The code was badly written and only IE behaved that way.

Comment: There is no setting in other browsers. You could use tampermonkey and its equivalents, but it would be a huge amount of work. You also could do right click  on the button and edit the source code of the button every time you use that page. But again thats not very convenient

Comment: https://www.sixteensmallstones.org/ie-javascript-bugs-overriding-internet-explorers-documentgetelementbyid-to-be-w3c-compliant-exposes-an-additional-bug-in-getattributes/ describes it in detail. This article was written in 2007...presumably your app was written to support some ancient version of IE - 6 or 7 maybe. If you _really_ can't change any of the code then there's nothing you can do. It uses non-standard techniques to select the elements, and these techniques are now obsolete, no modern browser supports them. I wouldn't be surprised if you can't even do this in newer IEs

Comment: Thanks - I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and it works correctly in that - I can't alter the code so I'll just have to get everyone to use Internet Explorer for this software!

Comment: @AndyGroom I would guess it works in IE11 only because something in the browser or page's settings (e.g. doctype, meta tags, browser settings) are telling it to run in an backwards-compatible mode - IE has modes for emulating its older versions. If you look in the IE developer tools you can see what mode it's in, and also temporarily change the mode so you can see how it behaves in each mode. As well as JS functionality changes you might well see visual changes as well, since IE's older versions are also notorious for non-standard HTML & CSS implementations. They were a nightmare for web devs

Answer (score -1):

Please check with below code

```
function checkCallLogIsValid (userId){
 var t = document.getElementById('select3');
 if (t.value == '' || t.value == '0'){
  alert ("You must provide a valid call type");
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: the question says, quite specifically, in bold text..."I cannot alter the code"